# How to parse json in flutter?

Tags: arrays, json, parsing, flutter, dart

I want to create a news app and I've used newsapi.org as a source.

I am trying to fetch the JSON data coming by the Http library.

I've provided the entire code below.

It doesn't give me any error but no data loaded and when I print the data it prints everything okay but I can't display it.

I don't what is the problem but all my project has stopped on this problem.

I am looking for a solution for this code because it doesn't work.

```dart
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart';
import 'package:newly/services/networking.dart';
import 'package:newly/widgets/article.dart';

class NewsScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _NewsScreenState createState() => _NewsScreenState();
}

class _NewsScreenState extends State<NewsScreen> {

  List<Article> articles = [];

  NetworkHelper networkHelper = NetworkHelper(
    url:
        'https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?q=bitcoin&apiKey=392495172bab4b3885ae93760df54b91',
  );

  Future<List<Widget>> getNews() async {
    var newsData = await networkHelper.getData();

    for (int i = 0; i < await newsData['articles'].length; i++) {
      var title = await newsData['articles'][i]['title'];
      var urlToImage = await newsData['articles'][i]['urlToImage'];
      var content = await newsData['articles'][i]['content'];
      var author = await newsData['articles'][i]['author'];
      var url = await newsData['articles'][i]['url'];

      print(title);
      print(urlToImage);
      print(url);
      print(content);
      print(author);
      print('123456789123456789123456789123456789');

      articles.add(
        Article(
          author: author,
          content: content,
          title: title,
          url: url,
          urlToImage: urlToImage,
        ),
      );

      print(articles[0].author);

    }

    return articles;
  }

  Future<List<Article>> showArticles() async {
    var data = await get(
      'https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?q=bitcoin&apiKey=392495172bab4b3885ae93760df54b91',
    );

    var dataDecoded = await json.decode(data.body);

    List<Article> articles = [];

    await dataDecoded.forEach(
      (article) {
        articles.add(
          Article(
            author: article['author'],
            content: article['content'],
            title: article['title'],
            url: article['url'],
            urlToImage: article['urlToImage'],
          ),
        );
      },
    );

    return articles;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text(
          'Newly',
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder(
        future: getNews(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          return ListView(
            children: articles,
          );
        },
      ),

    );
  }
}
```

Network Helper :

```dart
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

class NetworkHelper {
  NetworkHelper({this.url});

  final String url;

  Future getData() async {
    http.Response response = await http.get(url);

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      String data = response.body;

      return json.decode(data);
    } else {
      print('something wrong');
      print(response.statusCode);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: can you please show your `NetworkHelper` class?

Comment: I've updated now

Comment: Okay I will answer it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is in showing the articles. and yaa also as @ISpam Ossama says, you have to use setState for adding the data to list like this.

```
void getNews() async {
var newsData = await networkHelper.getData();

for (int i = 0; i < newsData['articles'].length; i++) {
  var title = newsData['articles'][i]['title'];
  var urlToImage = newsData['articles'][i]['urlToImage'];
  var content = newsData['articles'][i]['content'];
  var author = newsData['articles'][i]['author'];
  var url = newsData['articles'][i]['url'];

  print(title);
  print(urlToImage);
  print(url);
  print(content);
  print(author);
  print('123456789123456789123456789123456789');
  setState(() {
   articles.add(
    Article(
      author: author,
      content: content,
      title: title,
      url: url,
      urlToImage: urlToImage,
    ),
  );
  });
  print(articles[0].author);
}
}
```

Now, you have to display the articles like this.

```
ListView.builder(
          itemCount: articles.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctxt, int index) {
            return Text(articles[index].title);
          },
        )
```

Hope it will help you!

Comment: why are you use await in all statement ? Like, `await newsData['articles'][i]['title'];`

Comment: And also issue in setstate. because if we are getting 1000 data, then Widget will rebuild 1000 times. It should outside of for loop.

Comment: Yes you are right, I am really very sorry, I didn't noticed it, i will update the answer

Comment: I understood the await issue, but what is the alternate solution of the setState?

Comment: first add all data in local array and then setstate with global after for loop.

Comment: Thank you Abhay for giving me suggestion

Answer (score 9):

While working with **json data**

The good practice is to **create a model** for that and then just **fetch the data through the api**

creating a model and a class is easy enough and doesn't take effort and makes your work easy ;)

For **creating a model for your project**

**VISIT**     https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/

just `copy your json data` and `paste in the textField` and you will get your Model Class ready with just one click

for accessing the data

```
Test _test = Test.fromJson(response.body);
```

that's it.

refer image shown below

[image]

Comment: easy approach to convert model of response.

Comment: but still not getting data from response same error - the method '[]' was called on null.
E/flutter ( 8569): Receiver: null

Comment: @s.j the error reflects that from api end you are not getting any data, or may be you are not accessing it properly. Try to check the response first

Answer (score 2):

Try to setState before adding the articles to the array

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it using `FutureBuilder` , If you want otherwise as @Mustafa answer will work.

```
Future<List<Article>> showArticles() async {
var data = await networkHelper.getData();

List<Article> articlesArr = [];

await data['articles'].forEach(
  (article) {
    articlesArr.add(
      Article(
        author: article['author'],
        content: article['content'],
        title: article['title'],
        url: article['url'],
        urlToImage: article['urlToImage'],
      ),
    );
  },
);
return articlesArr;
}

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text(
          'Newly',
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder<List<Article>>(
        future: showArticles(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return ListView(
              children: snapshot.data.map((article) {
                return Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Text(article.author),
                );
              }).toList(),
            );
          } else {
            return Container(
              color: Colors.blue,
            );
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```