# Unable to load JSON data to show in ListView

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I need to get the json array data in flutter app by providing the get method.

The problem that I am facing is that I am  not able to put the records in the empty list carList.

but I am getting the array of objects as shown below(POSTMAN) by

print(json.decode(response.body)) // **in the file cars.dart**

Hence if you could please help me on how to get the response in the **List carlist = [];**

Car_list.dart file calls the method for the get request.

Please let me know if you require any further information from my end.

Thankyou

POSTMAN

```
[
{
"id": "1",
"carModel" : "Maruti swift",
"carDescription" : "The car has a top speed of 180 km/hr"
},
{
"id": "1",
"carModel" : "Hyundai santro",
"carDescription" : "The car has a top speed of 150 km/hr"
},
{
"id": "1",
"carModel" : "Hyundai creta",
"carDescription" : "The car has a top speed of 160 km/hr"
}
]
```

CarsModel.dart

```
class Cars with ChangeNotifier{
   String userId;
   String carModel
   String carDescription;


  Cars(
  {
    this.userId = '1111',
    this.carModel,
    this.carDescription,
  }
);

 factory Cars.fromJSON(Map<String,dynamic> json) => Cars(
     userId : json['userId'],
     carModel : json['CarModel'],
     carDescription : json['carDescription'],
 );


toJSON() {
  return {
    'userId':'111',
    'carModel':carModel,
    'carDescription' : carDescription
  };
}
```

cars.dart

```
class CarProvider with ChangeNotifier{

List<Cars> carlist = [
//Sample data to show the format in which the data needs to be shown as the listview gets populated from below records which we are supposed to get from postman 
//Cars (
//    userid: 1111,
//    carModel: 'Maruti Alto',
//    carDescription: 'Top speed 140 km/hr'


    ),
];

Future<void> readListofCars(int id) async {

 print(id.toString());


 const url = 'http://localhost/userlist';

// {'id': id.toString()

 Map<String, String> headers = {   
"Content-type": "application/json"};

try
  {
  final response = await http.get(url,headers: headers);

  List<dynamic> bodyCars = jsonDecode(response.body);

  List<Cars> loadedCars = bodyCars.map((dynamic item) => new Cars.fromJSON(item)).toList();


  /*
    for (Map i in bodyCars) {
    _notificationitems.add(Cars.fromJSON(i));
  }
 */

  });

 print(response.statusCode);
  carlist  = loadedCars; 
 print(json.decode(response.body));
 notifyListeners();

}catch (error){
  throw error;
}
}
```

Car_list.dart

```
class TabScreenCar extends StatefulWidget {

  final String userId;


  TabScreenCar(this.userId);

  @override
  _TabScreenCarState createState() => _TabScreenCarState();
}

class _TabScreenCarState extends State<TabScreenCar> {
@override
void didChangeDependencies() {
   final id = 1111;
    Provider.of<CarProvider>(context).readListofCars(id);

  super.didChangeDependencies(); 
}
```

Comment: Can you please print the error in the catch block of cars.dart

Comment: Hi wilson.... I am not getting any error.....so it seems the data is not getting inserted in the List  therefore the list returns empty and as a result the listview is empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your model class you have incorrect variable to fetch the json data

to make the process simple you can have a look at this link

https://stackoverflow.com/a/58708634/9236994

just paste your `json response` in https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/

and use the json model class which will be generated.

your issue will be resolved.

variable which you are using doesn't match with your json response

**OR to keep it simple**

use below mentioned `fromJSON` method

```
factory Cars.fromJSON(Map<String,dynamic> json) => Cars(
     userId : json['id'],
     carModel : json['carModel'],
     carDescription : json['carDescription'],
 );
```

**EDIT**

I think you are facing issue with setting up the data in your list variable too.

use below shown code to fill the response into list if cars data

```
List<Cars> loadedCars = List<Cars>();
var data = jsonDecode(response.body);

data.forEach((val) {
    loadedCars.add(Cars.fromJSON(val));
}
```

Comment: Hi vicky made the relevant changes but still facing the same issue

Comment: hi @akhilmodi I have added an edit to my answer regarding fill up the list do check out that too.