# How do i display progress bar on each item in the listview using flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

i have a json data which am displaying in the listview that contains item name, scores and target scores. i want to show a progress bar indicating scored points and the target points below is my code and images to help understand.
This is my json data
[image: This is my json data]

Below is My code:
`

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:network/network.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class FavouriteTab extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FavouriteTabState createState() => _FavouriteTabState();
}

class _FavouriteTabState extends State<FavouriteTab> {
  List products = List();

  Future getAllProducts() async {
    var response = await http.get(NetworkUrl.getProducts());
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      setState(() {
        products = json.decode(response.body);
      });
      return products;
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getAllProducts();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Target Scores"),
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder(
          future: getAllProducts(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              if (products.contains("empty")) {
                return Center(child: Text("NO DATA"));
              } else {
                return ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: products.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      var notis = products;
                      var scoredAmt = notis[index]['scored_amt'];
                      var targetAmt = notis[index]['target_score'];
                      var _percentages = (scoredAmt / targetAmt);
                      return Card(
                        child: Container(
                          child: Column(
                            children: [
                              Text(notis[index]['item_name']),
                              Text(
                                notis[index]['target_score'],
                                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.indigo),
                              ),
                              SizedBox(height: 5),
                              Row(
                                children: [
                                  Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                    child: Text("Scored Amount :" +
                                        notis[index]['scored_amt']),
                                  ),
                                  Spacer(),
                                  Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                    child: Text("Target Amount :" +
                                        notis[index]['target_score']),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                              Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                child: SizedBox(
                                    width: 300,
                                    height: 30,
                                    child: LinearProgressIndicator(
                                        value: _percentages)),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    });
              }
            } else {
              return LinearProgressIndicator(
                backgroundColor: Colors.purpleAccent,
              );
            }
          }),
    );
  }
}`
```

Am getting this error

[image: The Error am getting]

i want to have data display like this according to the scores:
This is how i want to display
[image]

I don't know what am doing wrong kindly help

Answer (score 2):

As the error you are getting denotes it seems that you are not parsing the strings as num's and are trying to divide Strings.

```dart
var _percentages = (num.tryParse(scoredAmt) / num.tryParse(targetAmt))
```

Or even better do that parsing in your model see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58706067/how-to-parse-json-in-flutter).

Also you are calling the getAllProducts in initState but are not caching the result and you call it again in the futureBuilder,

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:Habapay/network/network.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class FavouriteTab extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FavouriteTabState createState() => _FavouriteTabState();
}

class _FavouriteTabState extends State<FavouriteTab> {
  List products = List();
  Future allProducts;
  Future getAllProducts() async {
    var response = await http.get(NetworkUrl.getProducts());
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      setState(() {
        products = json.decode(response.body);
      });
      return products;
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    allProducts=  getAllProducts();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Target Scores"),
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder(
          future: allProducts,/// Now the future gets called only once
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              if (products.contains("empty")) {
                return Center(child: Text("NO DATA"));
              } else {
                return ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: products.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      var notis = products;
                      var scoredAmt = notis[index]['scored_amt'];
                      var targetAmt = notis[index]['target_score'];
                      var _percentages = (scoredAmt / targetAmt);
                      return Card(
                        child: Container(
                          child: Column(
                            children: [
                              Text(notis[index]['item_name']),
                              Text(
                                notis[index]['target_score'],
                                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.indigo),
                              ),
                              SizedBox(height: 5),
                              Row(
                                children: [
                                  Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                    child: Text("Scored Amount :" +
                                        notis[index]['scored_amt']),
                                  ),
                                  Spacer(),
                                  Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                    child: Text("Target Amount :" +
                                        notis[index]['target_score']),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                              Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                child: SizedBox(
                                    width: 300,
                                    height: 30,
                                    child: LinearProgressIndicator(
                                        value: _percentages)),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    });
              }
            } else {
              return LinearProgressIndicator(
                backgroundColor: Colors.purpleAccent,
              );
            }
          }),
    );
  }
}`
```