# Store List of Objects or Map in SharedPreference using dart

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I am returning data from MySQL in `JSON` using this piece of code

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($queryResult)) {
$resultArray[]=$row;      
}
echo json_encode($resultArray);
```

The result is in this format

```
[{
"reg_number": "FA16-BCS-106",
"teacher_id": "1",
"qr_code": "jamshaid",
"course_name": "COURSE 1"
}, {
"reg_number": "FA16-BCS-106",
"teacher_id": "EMP_FA10_10",
"qr_code": "jamoo",
"course_name": "COURSE 2"
}]
```

I am decoding the response and storing it in a list using this method which is working fine.

```
class Student {
final String reg_number;
final String teacher_id;
final String qr_code;
final String course_name;

Student({this.reg_number, this.teacher_id, this.qr_code, this.course_name});

 factory Student.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
return Student(
  reg_number: json['reg_number'],
  teacher_id: json['teacher_id'],
  qr_code: json['qr_code'],
  course_name: json['course_name'],
);
}
}
 final parsed =
          json.decode(jsonResponse.body).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();
      List<Student> st =
          parsed.map<Student>((json) => Student.fromJson(json)).toList();
```

I am trying to store this List of objects of Student class in SharedPreference using version ^0.5.6. There is no direct method available for this. I've tried using [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55832454/11877320) but having the following error.

> Unhandled Exception: type 'List' is not a subtype of type 'Map'

`jsonResponse.body` is supposed to be a string but it is reading it as `List<dynamic>`. Why is that happening? Am I doing anything wrong while parsing the result? Thanks

Comment: You can store key-value pair in shared prefs, thats means it is type of Map not List.

Comment: @Blasanka how can I do that? I am a newbie to Dart. I've been working in Java before this and there it wasn't the difficult case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple example created for you to understand how to do this. This is ok for small list but if you have a large list, I dont recommend this because of we are doing too much stuff here.

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class Todo {
  final String title;
  final String description;

  Todo(this.title, this.description);

  Todo.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> map) :
        title = map["title"],
        description = map["description"];

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {
    "title": title,
    "description": description
  };
}

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    title: 'Passing Data',
    home: HomePage(
      todos: List.generate(
        20, (i) => Todo(
          'Todo $i',
          'A description of what needs to be done for Todo $i',
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ));
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Todo> todos;

  HomePage({this.todos}) {
    saveTodos();
  }

  void saveTodos() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    List<String> values =  todos.map((item) => json.encode(item.toMap())).toList();
    prefs.setStringList("todos", values);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TodosScreen();
  }
}


class TodosScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _StateTodosScreen();
  }
}

class _StateTodosScreen extends State<TodosScreen> {

  Future<List<Todo>> getTodos() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    List<String> values = prefs.getStringList("todos");
    return values.map((item) => Todo.fromJson(json.decode(item))).toList();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Todos'),
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder(
        future: getTodos(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return ListTile(
                  title: Text(snapshot.data[index].title),
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => DetailScreen(todo: snapshot.data[index]),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                );
              },
            );
          } else {
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class DetailScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final Todo todo;

  DetailScreen({Key key, @required this.todo}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(todo.title),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: Text(todo.description),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

But you can simply encode your complete json and store, there will not be much work then, but if it is a complex json you have to handle that also.

Comment: The `toMap()` and parsing lines in `saveTodos` and `getTodos` did the trick. Thanks