# How can I make the reserved seats unselectable?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I tried to make a travel booking app, but I am confused how to make the reserved seats can not be selected again. I use `StaggeredGridView` to display seat options, each `Container` in `StaggeredGridView` has an index. I can save the `index` of the selected seat with `.sublist ()`, but I'm confused where I have to save the index so that the `index` can later be used to make the seats can not be selected again (disabled). And how to check that the seat `index` is an `index` of a particular car?

[This is a picture of what I'm talking about to make it clearer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZAZwo.jpg)

## --EDIT (add the code)--

Here Is the code for displaying the seats

```
class Kursi extends StatefulWidget {
  Function onTapKursi, sisaKursi, bookedKursi;
  Kursi({this.onTapKursi, this.sisaKursi, this.bookedKursi});

  @override
  _KursiState createState() => _KursiState();
}
class _KursiState extends State<Kursi> {
  
  List<String> _listSeats = List();
  List<int> _selectedIndexList = List();
  String amount, availableSeat, idCar; 
  int amountInt, idCarInt, totalPassenger, availableSeatInt;

  getPref()async{
    SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
      idCar = preferences.getString('id_armada');
      amount = preferences.getString('kursi');
      availableSeat = preferences.getString('sisaKursi');
      totalPassenger = preferences.getInt('jumlah');
      idCarInt = int.parse(idCar);
      amountInt = int.parse(amount);
      availableSeatInt = int.parse(availableSeat);
      for (var i = 1; i <= amountInt; i++) {
       _listSeats.add(i.toString());
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    getPref();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(
      child: StaggeredGridView.countBuilder(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 0, bottom: 0),
        crossAxisSpacing: 70,
        mainAxisSpacing: 7,
        crossAxisCount: 2,
        itemCount: _listSeats.length,
        staggeredTileBuilder: (int index) => StaggeredTile.fit(1),
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return GridTile(
            child: InkWell(
              child: Container(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: _selectedIndexList.contains(index)
                        ? Colors.purple
                        : Color(0xFFFf6f5fb),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8)),
                    border: Border.all(
                        color: Colors.black,
                        width: 2,
                        style: BorderStyle.solid)),
                height: 30,
                width: 30,
                child: Text(
                  _listSeats[index],
                ),
              ),
              onTap: () {
                if (_selectedIndexList.length < totalPassenger || _selectedIndexList.contains(index)) {
                  setState(() {
                  if (_selectedIndexList.contains(index)) {
                    _selectedIndexList.remove(index);
                  } else {
                    _selectedIndexList.add(index);
                  }
                });
                } else {
                  return null;
                }
                this.widget.onTapKursi(index);
                this.widget.sisaKursi(availableSeatInt, _selectedIndexList.length);
                this.widget.bookedKursi(_selectedIndexList.sublist(0));
              },
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: If the widget you're implementing is based on a button, usually supplying `null` as the `onTap` handler will make the button *unclickable*. Maybe that's what you need?

Comment: @loganrussell48 yeah, i used `InkWell` that have an `onTap` function, but i want to make the reserved seats cannot be selected by the same user or other users. And the seats index is part of car table. By the way, sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a class that represents each car, with an id and a map of seats where you can set if is selected or not. If selected you set the index and the flag to true, otherwise, to false:

```
class Car {
    
   int id
   int seatsAmount; //amount of seats
   Map<int, bool> seats; //map of seats

   Car(this.id);

   //method to initialize the seats map with false to indicate not reserved
   initSeatsMap(){
    for(int i=0; i<numOfSeats; i++){
      this.seats[i] = false;
    }
  }
}

Car someCar = Car(1);
someCar.initSeatsMap();
```

Then you can check when call the select (or onTap) function:

```
onTap: someCar.seats[index] == false 
                    ? 
                    () { 
                     someCar.seats[index] = true; 
                     //write some code to change the color of the seat
                    } 
                    : 
                    null; // null means that when you tap after a seat is selected the onTap will do nothing;
```

When you get the seats from shared preferences you can do like this:

```
Car anyCar = Car(idCar);
//The result is something like this: 
anyCar.seats = json.decode(sharedPreferencesSeats);
```

or just create a Map like this:

```
Map<int, bool> seats = json.decode(sharedPreferencesSeats);
```

Then you can check the reserved seats like this:

```
// or seats.forEach(...) if you create the Map
anyCar.seats.forEach((key,value){
    if(value == true){
      print('Seat $key - Reserved');
    }else{
      print('Seat $key - Availabe');
    }
  } );
```

Comment: but if i use `anyCar.seats = json.decode(sharedPreferencesSeats);`, wouldn't that make every car have the same seat data when idCar is different? sorry if I ask a lot

Comment: Yes, idCar is the identifier of a car, isn't? For each car that you create you need to store the idCar and the map of seats for this idCar. Because of this you need the model.

Comment: what is on my mind is if I choose 2 seats in a car with idCar 1, then save it. Then when I or another user will choose a seat in a car with idCar 2, does it mean the seat on idCar 2 should be different from idCar 1? seats on idCar 1 will have 2 seats that are true, but on idCar 2 all seats should be false. So, if I use `anyCar.seats = json.decode(sharedPreferencesSeats);` for idCar 2, idCar 2 will also have 2 seats that are true like idCar 1, right? because previously I saved 2 seats, even though it should only be for idCar 1

Comment: Yes. But you need to save an instance of your Car model for each car you create. You can't use just one field to store the seats. To see how to store a model (object) in SharedPreferences, take a look at this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53931513/store-data-as-an-object-in-shared-preferences-in-flutter) or search for some tutorials. But SharedPreferences stores data just locally in your device and if you have to intend to make your app online where many user access the booking, you must consider to use Firestore database by example.

Answer (score 1):

Reserved or non-reserved should be part of your seating model. What that means is that your seat model should be able to tell whether it is reserved or not.

Your UI layout would just check this status from seat and make the required adjustments. Something along this line:

```
class Seat {
    //other members
    boolean reserved;
}
```

UI:

```
if(seat.reserved) {
     //handle reserved seat
 } else {
     //handle un-reserved seat
 }
```