# Flutter & Shared Preferences : How do I save a list (of object) to local memory?

Tags: flutter, dart, caching, sharedpreferences

I want to save a list of objects into my local memory using the `shared_preferences` package.

Let's assume that this is my class:

```
class Person{
   String name;
   String age;
   String gender;
}
```

How do I do that with `shared_preferences`?

I am looking forward to hearing from all of you. Thank you.

Comment: It's better to use `sqflite` or `hive` for saving and restoring list of objects. `shared_preference` is preferred when you want to save and restore a value (`int`, `String` ...etc) not a list.

Comment: Though it's not preferred to store object in Shared Preference, here look at the second answer if you still want. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53931513/store-data-as-an-object-in-shared-preferences-in-flutter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can save a `List<String>` with `shared_preferences`.
Therefore, we need to convert the `Person` class, and its list, into a `String` by encoding them as `JSON`:

```
class Person {
    String name;
    String age;
    String gender;
    Person({this.name, this.age, this.gender});

    factory Person.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> parsedJson) {
        return new Person(
            name: parsedJson['name'] ?? "",
            age: parsedJson['age'] ?? "",
            gender: parsedJson['gender'] ?? "");
    }

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
        return {
          "name": this.name,
          "age": this.age,
          "gender": this.gender,
        };
    }
}

void _savePersons(List<Person> persons) async {
   SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
   List<String> personsEncoded = persons.map((person) => jsonEncode(person.toJson())).toList();
   await sharedPreferences.setStringList('persons', personsEncoded );
}
```

In the same fashion, we can get the saved `List<Person>` as a `JSON` object and de-serialize it:

```
List<Person> _getPersons(List<Person> persons) async {
   SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  final persons = await sharedPreferences.setStringList('persons', accounts);
   return persons.map((person) => Person.fromJson(person)).toList();
}
```