# How i can store json response in Shared Prefence in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I want to store an this Json response in shared preferences which contains one fields in it password  and my response is

```
{
    "id": 103,
    "address": "ce5f4e2b82a901768456b0dfd58e7dfa99a1bd0e",
    "privateKey": "91c8b3434a7eb8eb6df73cd7dfbfa3d7cce66d5f4f635fb6d329894c69fa0cab",
    "status": "succeed",
    "password": "1245687"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

//Save the value

prefs.setString("json_response", json.encode(value));

//Read the value

var value = json.decode(prefs.getString(json_response))

Comment: What i should write in value field the api response field or any thing else..

Comment: Yes you have to pass the json which you want to store

Answer (score 0):

I have answered a similar question which answers to handling of json data with SharedPreferences in flutter

Refer the answer here 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/63413787/9236994

Comment: So which one is correct in your Answer list ....

Comment: have shared the link to my answer you can refer that @atifRaza