# How to save the canvas drawPath to device using shared Preference

Tags: flutter

I'm making a e-book application and user can draw lines on the `Container` widget which stacked on the `Pdfviewer` and I want to make the drawn lines are saved to the user's device by using a Shared Preference or other ways.

here's my code

```
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        elevation: 1,
      ),
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          InteractiveViewer(
            panEnabled: _memoMode ? false : true,
            scaleEnabled: _memoMode ? false : true,
            maxScale: 3,
            child: Stack(
              children: [
                IgnorePointer(
                  ignoring: true,
                  child: SfPdfViewer.network(
                    widget.downloadedURL,
                    controller: _pdfViewerController,
                    key: _pdfViewerKey,
                    pageLayoutMode: PdfPageLayoutMode.single,
                    enableDoubleTapZooming: false,
                    // Save the last closed page number
                    onPageChanged: (details) {
                      _lastClosedPage = details.newPageNumber;
                      _currentPage = details.newPageNumber;
                      countLastClosedPage();
                    },
                    onDocumentLoaded: (details) {
                      // PDF Open 하면 memo page와 문제집 page를 matching
                      _pdfViewerController.jumpToPage(_lastClosedPage);
                      _pdfViewerController.zoomLevel = 0;
                      print("totalpages = ${_countTotalPages().toInt()}");

                    },
                    canShowScrollHead: false,
                  ),
                ),
               // User can draw lines on the WorkbookDrawingPage widget 
                SingleChildScrollView(
                  physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                  controller: _scrollController,
                  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                  child: WorkbookDrawingPage(widget.workbookName, _countTotalPages().toInt()),
                ),
```

> WorkbookDawingPage.dart

```
    return Container(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * (widget.countTotalPages),
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 1,
      child: CustomPaint(
        painter: DrawingPainter(p.lines, widget.workbookName),
        child: Listener(
         ...
         ...
```

> DrawingPainter.dart

```
class DrawingPainter extends CustomPainter {

  final List<List<DotInfo>> lines;
  String workbookName;

  DrawingPainter(this.lines, this.workbookName);

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) async {

      for (var oneLine in lines) {
        Color? color;
        double? size;
        var path = Path();
        var l = <Offset>[];
        for (var oneDot in oneLine) {
          color ??= oneDot.color;
          size ??= oneDot.size;
          l.add(oneDot.offset);
        }
        path.addPolygon(l, false);
        canvas.drawPath(
            path,
            Paint()
              ..color = color!
              ..strokeWidth = size!
              ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round
              ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
              ..isAntiAlias = true
              ..strokeJoin = StrokeJoin.round);

      }

  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) => true;
}
```

Is there any ways to save the drawn lines?

Answer (score 0):

As stated by the [shared_preferences](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/main/packages/shared_preferences/shared_preferences) library, you can only store certain data types directly:
`Supported data types are int, double, bool, String and List<String>.`

What you can do, is convert your `DotInfo` to a JSON, and then store it as a stringified version in your storage. If you need to fetch your data aftwards, you can decode your stringified version back to a JSON and show it as intended.

You can check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53931513/store-data-as-an-object-in-shared-preferences-in-flutter) for how to do this!